# Using Path Parameters on a post method in a Jersey rest Service

Tags: rest, post, jersey

Could someone kindly advice on whether its possible to use path params on a POST method.I have this POST method that does not seem to receive the path parameters

```
@POST
@Path("/newUser/{fname}/{lname}/{idno}")
Response addName(@PathParam("fname") String fName,
                    @PathParam("lname") String lName,
                    @PathParam("idno") String idNo);



@Override
public Response addName(@PathParam("fname") String fName,
                           @PathParam("sname") String sName,
                           @PathParam("idno") String idNo) {
   System.out.println("Inside add User");


   return Response.status(200).entity("User Added").build();
 }
```

A post request to this method does not succeed as the line  "Inside add User" is not ouput.Please where am I not doing it right? I will appreciate

Comment: Get rid of the `@PathParam` annotations on the overriden method

Comment: @peeskillet  I get this error from the overriding method "Method does not overide or implement a method from a super type"

Comment: Is the code you are showing in the same class? The first snippet of code should be in an `interface`, and the second should be in a concrete class that implements the interface. It would help if you showed complete code

Comment: @peeskillet Thats true One is in the interface and the other one from the class that implements the interface

Comment: Annotations have no effect on how you override a method, if that's what you are thinking. I don't why you are getting that error. I can't reproduce the problem with what little you've provided

Comment: Here is the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line from your interface.

```
@Path("/newUser/{fname}/{lname}/{idno}")
```

And also remove the `@PathParam` annotations from the implementation class.

You create a new class `User.java` and place all these fields there.
And implement as follows, the mime type can be a decision from you.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/newuser")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addName(User user) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sharma for the answer.i however wanted to know if I can implement with only the path params  instead of the JSON resource

Comment: If path params or query params are your choice of implementation, you have to use the @GET.